# Error Establishing a Database Connection, but credentials are OK

Tags: errors

I'm migrating a WordPress website to a dedicated server, and am encountering the infamous "Error establishing a database connection" error. I've read [similar questions](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=error%20establishing%20database%20connection), and a number of blog posts on the subject, but I'm still stuck:

- My main page says "Error establishing a database connection"
- My wp-admin page says "One or more database tables are unavailable. The database may need to be repaired."

I've performed the following verifications:

- I've verified the credentials in `wp-config.php`. When using them on the command-line, I can access the database, and have all access rights to create tables, and CRUD rows.
- I have defined `WP_DEBUG` and `WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY` in `wp-config.php`, but the error message is still as vague.
- I have defined `WP_ALLOW_REPAIR` in `wp-config.php` and executed `/wp-admin/maint/repair.php`:

> The wp_users table is okay.
>   The wp_usermeta table is okay.
>   The wp_posts table is okay.
>   The wp_comments table is okay.
>   The wp_links table is okay.
>   The wp_options table is okay.
>   The wp_postmeta table is okay.
>   The wp_terms table is okay.
>   The wp_term_taxonomy table is okay.
>   The wp_term_relationships table is okay.
>   The wp_commentmeta table is okay.
>   Repairs complete.

Yet, I'm still getting the same error messages.

I'm starting to wonder if the backup I was given (I did not make this backup) contains all the required tables. Here are the tables that were in the backup:

- wp_adrotate
- wp_adrotate_groups
- wp_adrotate_linkmeta
- wp_adrotate_schedule
- wp_adrotate_stats
- wp_adrotate_tracker
- wp_cntctfrm_field
- wp_commentmeta
- wp_comments
- wp_duplicator_packages
- wp_ewwwio_images
- wp_links
- wp_options
- wp_postmeta
- wp_posts
- wp_term_relationships
- wp_term_taxonomy
- wp_terms
- wp_usermeta
- wp_users
- wp_wpmm_subscribers

What can be causing this error? Is there a way to get a detailed error message?

The WordPress version is `4.1.16` and the DB revision is `30135`.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be missing the wp_termmeta table, which I'm guessing was omitted from the backup.

Here's a 'create table' syntax for this table (you may have to tweak this depending on your MySQL version)

```
CREATE TABLE `wp_termmeta` (
  `meta_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `term_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `meta_key` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `meta_value` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci,
  PRIMARY KEY (`meta_id`),
  KEY `term_id` (`term_id`),
  KEY `meta_key` (`meta_key`(191))
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci;
```

Comment: Here is a version from a different one of my local DBs in case this is more helpful: `CREATE TABLE `wp_termmeta` (
  `meta_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `term_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `meta_key` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `meta_value` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  PRIMARY KEY (`meta_id`),
  KEY `term_id` (`term_id`),
  KEY `meta_key` (`meta_key`(191))
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;`

Comment: I did try creating this table, but the error persists I'm afraid!

Comment: sorry to hear it!  I note that you are using an older WP version.  Does your codebase match (ie are you using the files for version 4.1.16)?  Have you tried using the latest WordPress and just letting it try to update the database?